# 3801 HGV Admin interface will not load

Tags: wireless-networking, router, administrator

First thanks for any and all help. I have done extensive searching on this and have turn up nothing so far so I hope I may be able to get some answers here.

I have been trying to simply access the Admin interface of my 3801 HGV Router (Made by 2WIRE/PACE and provided by CENTURY LINK). My problem is, the interface will not load completely. By that I mean the HTML will not fill out, there are menus missing our not labeled etc. It keeps me from performing even the most basic tasks.

I have tried different browsers (Chrome, IE9, Firefox) as well as trying the different IP/DNS names to access the router interface. I have disabled all Firewalls/AV software. I simply do not know what else to try.

Comment: Have you tried any of the compatibility mode features in IE? Perhaps IE8 or 6?

Comment: I tried the compatibility mode in IE9 with no luck. As far as trying IE8 or 6 will i be able to run a version when I am running win7? All the versions i can find are for XP/Vista

Comment: In IE9 you can run compatibility mode by pressing F12 to get into developer tools, then selecting IE8 or 7 from the Browser Mode dropdown. (Sorry when I meant IE6 I meant 7 in my above comment.)

Comment: Hmm. I tried all of those settings with no luck at all.